# How to build a widget that can be placed into the Desktop of MacOS?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, widget, osx-today-widget

I have seen "widgets" on MacOS like for [weather](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/weather-widget-desktop/id1235020875?mt=12) and calendar, that can be used as something that I would call a "Desktop Widget":

[image]

It seems to be similar to a Today-widget, but can be placed on the desktop and will be "non touchable". There are no clicks, no dragging available as soon as in their preferences pain is the drag and resize option allowed.

Basically it feels like something natively being part of the desktop / wallpaper.

I want to build a similar thing with another approach than to show the current weather (for example a list of shares or currency trading pairs or what ever else)

What is the name or the term of this thing in Apple naming scope?
Where can I find the right framework to build on?
Where can I find some documentation about?

Comment: If it's downloaded from the App store, and if it's located in the Applications folder, then it probably is an app.

Comment: Yes, it is an App in the applications folder. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Check [HUD-Style Panels](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/panels/)  or NSWindowStyleMaskHUDWindow

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing term you are after is "Window", windows not only have a front/back ordering they are also grouped into *levels*. There is a level for "floating" windows, which is in front of the level for normal windows and so windows at this level always appear in front of standard windows. Similarly there is a "desktop" window level which is behind the other levels. There is a property `level` on `NSWindow` to get/set the level a window belongs to. The type [`NSWindowLevel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowlevel?language=objc) provides constants for *some* of the window levels, for all of them see [`CGWindowLevelKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgwindowlevelkey?language=objc).

Any window can be set to ignore clicks etc.

Combine the above and you should be able to create a translucent window "stuck" to the desktop which ignores clicks. HTH